# the meaning of this line: username: str | None = None?

Tags: python-3.x

I'm reading the documentation of a python libarary and I got blocked in this code, I coudn't understand the meaning :

```
class TokenData(BaseModel):
    username: str | None = None
```

what's the effect of ' | None = None ' on the attribute username ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a [union](https://peps.python.org/pep-0604/) [type hint](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html), similar to:

```
class TokenData(BaseModel):
    username: Union[str, None] = None
```

It basically means:

> `username` may be any value of type `str` or may be `None`, and by default it is initialized to `None`